# Difference between 後にも and 後には?

Tags: particle-は, particle-も

In an [IMABI article on 後](https://www.imabi.net/after.htm), the author explains the difference between  **～後には** and **～後にも**:

> It's also possible to see ～後には and ～後にも. The meanings of the individual particles do not behave any differently. **If you wish to emphasize that Action/State B occurs right after Action A, you use ～後にも. If you wish to emphasize that Action B/State B occurs right after Action A, then you use ～後には.**

I believe the author made a mistake in the bolded sentence, since he says the same thing about both ～後には and  ～後にも?

**Question:** What is the difference between the following 3 sentences? (I put my guesses in parentheses).

1. 嵐の**後に**凪が来る。 ("After a storm comes the calm")
2. 嵐の**後にも**凪が来る。("*Even* after a storm comes the calm"?)
3. 嵐の**後には**凪が来る。("After *as little as a storm* comes the calm"??)

Comment: This is about the general difference between は and も has little to do with 後.

Comment: You can ignore the bold part and should just note about the preceding "The meanings of the individual particles do not behave any differently."

Answer (score 1):

- 嵐の後に凪が来る。 ("After a storm comes the calm") -> OK.
- 嵐の後にも凪が来る。("Even after a storm comes the calm") -> OK
- 嵐の後には凪が来る。 -> I think "A calm always comes after a storm"

Comment: The article from which George has quoted seems to be at least **trying** to say that either 嵐の後には凪が来る or 嵐の後にも凪が来る means "A calm comes *right* after a storm" -- but as a result of the error George points out, it instead says that **both** alternatives mean that. Your answer implies but doesn't quite state that in fact **neither** of the two alternatives includes the "right after" nuance. If that's what you mean, I think you could strengthen your answer by saying so explicitly. (I'm pointing this out because I myself would like to know if either one does have that nuance.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert, so I could be wrong, but based on what I've seen (and my general understanding of the particles involved too), I would interpret those sentences as:

嵐の後に凪が来る。　"After the storm comes the calm" (suggesting a specific instance)
嵐の後にも凪が来る。"After even a storm comes a calm" (in addition to other things that calm comes after)
嵐の後には凪が来る。"After a storm comes a calm" (in general)